# Pascal records mixing word and bytes in records doesn't work as expected

Tags: delphi, record, pascal

My data is like this (one byte each two '-'):

```
+----+--+----+----+
|0840|0C|00AD|0840|
+----+--+----+----+
```

If I use this code: **WRONG**

```
Type TAlarmasRATP = record
   Funcion   : word;
   Instancia : byte;
   Err_0     : word;
   Err_1     : word;
end;
```

Funcion = 4008, Instancia = 0C, Err_0 = 08AD, Err_1 = 0040

If I use this code: **RIGHT**

```
Type TAlarmasRATP = record
   Funcion   : word;
   Instancia : byte;
   Err_0     : array [0..1] of byte;
   Err_1     : array [0..1] of byte;
end;
```

Funcion = 4008, Instancia = 0C, Err_0 = AD00, Err_1 = 4008

Why the first one is not working?

Comment: Try with a `packed record`.

Comment: @Olivier many thanks, it is solving the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a record type is used, fields are aligned according to the specification [Internal data formats - Record types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Record_Types):

| type | alignment in bytes (32bit platform) |
| --- | --- |
| ordinal | size of the type (i.e. 1 for `Byte`, 2 for `Word`, 4 for `Cardinal`, or 8 for `Int64`) |
| real | 2 for `Real48`, 4 for `Single`, 8 for `Double` and `Extended` |
| `ShortString` | 1 |
| `Array` | Same as the element type of the array |
| `Record` | The largest alignment of the fields in the record |
| `Set` | Size of the type (1, 2, or 4), otherwise always 1 |
| all other | Determined by the `{$A}` directive |

That means: in the first record declaration the `Err_0` field will be aligned on a `Word` boundary and that will append one padding byte after the `Instancia` field.

In the second record declaration the `Err_0` field will be aligned on a `Byte` boundary, because it is an array of `Byte` and there will be no padding after the `Instancia` field. Since the record is not packed, a padding byte will be inserted at the end of the structure - so the record sizes will be rounded to 8 in both cases.

If you use the `packed` keyword all fields in the record will be packed to the byte boundary and the size of the record will be exactly the sum of the field sizes, with no padding at the end.

For having a record size of 7 you can simply declare:

```
type TAlarmasRATP = packed record
   Funcion   : Word;
   Instancia : Byte;
   Err_0     : Word;
   Err_1     : Word;
end;
```

However, if you need a size of 8 you should manually add a padding byte at the end by defining just another field that you never use:

```
type TAlarmasRATP = packed record
   Funcion   : Word;
   Instancia : Byte;
   Err_0     : Word;
   Err_1     : Word;
   Padding   : Byte;  // Unused
end;
```